# Split 100-AA-1001A/B/C into Array 100-AA-1001A, 100-AA-1001B, 100-AA-1001C Using Regexp

Tags: regex, vb.net, split

I have the text **100-AA-1001A/B/C** in a .txt file.

I would ideally like to be able to use a regular expression (or minimal VB coding) to split the text at the forward slash and include the 'prefix' to create an array of:

- **100-AA-1001A**
- **100-AA-1001B**
- **100-AA-1001C**

I imagine it will be some kind of bracketing of the expression along the lines of:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

    Sub RegexpSplitTxt()
        Dim pattern As String = "(\d{3}-[A-Z]{2}-\d{4})[A-Z]?(\/[A-Z])?(\/[A-Z])?"
        Dim replacement As String = "$2"
        Dim input As String = "100-AA-1001A/B/C"
        Dim result As String = Regexp ($1 Somewhere) & Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement)
        Console.WriteLine(result)
    End Sub
```

At the moment I am manually using Excel which is very time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is always as you have shown then you just need to split the string on the slashes and replace the last character with each of the parts from the split:

```
Dim s = "100-AA-1001A/B/C"
Dim parts = s.Split("/"c)
Dim derived As New List(Of String)

derived.Add(parts(0))

For i = 1 To parts.Count - 1
    derived.Add(parts(0).Remove(parts(0).Length - 1) & parts(i))
Next

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, derived))
Console.ReadLine()
```

Outputs:

> 100-AA-1001A
>   100-AA-1001B
>   100-AA-1001C

You could get an array from `derived` with `derived.ToArray()` if you *really* need an array.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, the derived.add(parts) was exactly what I needed.  I modified your code ever so slightly to allow for different string lengths between the forward slashes..  derived.Add(parts(0).Remove(parts(0).Length - Len(parts(i))) & parts(i))